# Bounds on dimension of cokernel of $Sym^2(H^0(X,D)) \to H^0(X,2D)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb C$. Let $D$ be a divisor on it. What is known about upper bound on dimension of the cokernel of
$$Sym^2(H^0(X,D)) \to H^0(X,2D)?$$
In my case the divisor $D$ is somewhat larger than half of the canonical divisor,
dimension of $H^0(X,D)$ is $O(n)$, while dimension of $H^0(X,2D)$ and genus of $X$ are $O(n^2)$.

I am interested in upper bounds (presumably with some conditions on $X$) of
order $O(n)$ or some small constant times genus.
Any references will be appreciated.

Comment: what is $n$ here?

Comment: I actually have a family of curves (these are modular curves). The point is that the dimension of $H^0(X,D)$ is up to a constant the root of the genus. Also, the map is definitely not surjective, but I would like to bound the defect.

Comment: Lev, I don't know the answer to your question, but am incidentally interested in what happens when X is a modular curve and  D is a half canonical divisor plus a small number of points. Do you have any thoughts or knowledge about this?